# Server re-starter Timeline, Seconds Minutes Hours

Tags: windows, batch-file

How can I make my command/ batch file show a better timeline?

```
@echo off
              title Server Restarter
       :start
              set time=18000
              start (exefile).exe
       :loop
              cls
              IF %time% GTR 0 (
               set /a time=%time% - 1
                set /a min=%time%/5
                set /a hrs=%time%/10
                 echo (servername) will Restart In %time% Seconds.
                echo (servername) will Restart in %time% Seconds, %min% Minutes, %hrs% Hours.
               ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > NUL
              goto loop
              ) 
       taskkill /f /im (exefile).exe
      cls
     close server
     goto start
```

Is there a way to make the code show like this,

> Minutes 0-59 Seconds 0-59 Hours 0-24 Days 0-(number)

etc? I tried many thing but couldn't get the hours to show correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation is a bit too easy.

```
@echo off
set tim=180000

:loop
 cls
 IF %tim% leq 0 goto done
 set /a day=%tim%/86400
 set /a hrs=(%tim%-day*86400)/3600
 set /a min=(%tim%-day*86400-%hrs%*3600)/60
 set /a sec=%tim%-day*86400-%hrs%*3600-%min%*60 
 echo servername will Restart In %tim% Seconds.
 echo servername will Restart in %day% days, %hrs% hours, %min% Minutes and %sec% seconds.
 ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > NUL
 set /a tim-=1
goto loop

:done
echo done.
```

Your main problem was that your code uses variable in a block (inside `(`and `)`), so that you would need delayed expansion. You can avoid it by clever use of the condition.

By the way: i used `%tim%`instead of `%time%` because `%time%` is a system variable - bad idea to mess with them - even if it works.